# How to reload an activity when dialog box is closed in another activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

In my application I'm using one dialog box. When the user presses OK it goes to another activity by passing an intent. This is my code:

```
dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(EditDeleteReqCardList.this, RequestcardList.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        dialog.dismiss();    
    }
});
```

When passing to `RequestcardList.class`, I also want to reload the `RequestcardList` page. How can I do this in the dialog box's `onclick` listener?

Comment: RequestcardList is an activity ?

Comment: what problem are you getting now?

Comment: which activity do you want to reload?

Comment: Hi, in my dialog box in the EditDeleteReqCardList activity, when i press OK button , it will start a new intent and open RequestcardList activity, at the same time , i need to reload RequestcardList class, thats my problem

Comment: I want to reload RequestcardList activity

Comment: If anybody know, please help me,

Comment: if your in activity EditDeleteReqCardList and you want to reload  RequestcardList activity then you are in right path... what is the problem here? pls expln your problem ..

Comment: ya your right vnshetty, my problem is in requestcardList activity, data is comiing from the server.in the EditDeleteReqCardList activity, i delete one data from the RequestcardList, after going back to RequestcardList using intent from the  EditDeleteReqCardList , the  RequestcardList is not updated, it still showing the previous data. thats my problem,iam week in english..please help me

Comment: can you post both the files? bcoz i dint undrstand your flow

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26076/discussion-between-vnshetty-and-sibinf)

Comment: hi still i have the same problem, see i created RequestcardList  as tab , that activity displays a listview , when i click each list item , it will go to EditDeleteReqCardList ,from where we can able to delete the listitem. for that i create one button in the   EditDeleteReqCardList(that is not a tab), when i click on that button , a dialoug box will appear, when i click , delete action is perfrmed and go back to requestcardlist activity. but my problem is when i go back to requestcardlist , it stll shows the old data, i want to reload that activity , how it possible?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26083/discussion-between-sibinf-and-vnshetty)

Answer (score 0):

try : protected void onNewIntent (Intent intent)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent%28android.content.Intent%29

> You can use setIntent(Intent) to update it to this new Intent.